# How to die website if database connection cannot be established

Tags: php, mysqli, try-catch, die

I have a website with a database connection. The connection is very important for the website, so I need to 'die' the website if it can't establish a database connection. The 'or die' isn't a good idea, so I tried this:

```
$host='localhost';
$un='root';
$pw='mypass';
$dbname='home';

try {
    $db = new mysqli($host, $un, $pw, $dbname);
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        throw new Exception('Fail: '.$db->connect_errno);
    }
} 
    catch(Exception $e) 
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

But then, the user can see the error message:

```
mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: no such host is known

Fail: 2002
```

What is the best way to check if the connection is ok, and if not: die the website with an error message?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just log the error message and `echo` whatever you want to show.

Comment: No, an error occurs when defining the object

Comment: @Jordy Can it connect 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, it can connect, but I changed to host to 'asdfasdf' for example to check what happens if there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Will print a message and terminate the script

Comment: You mean, that it's not handled by the exception? Can you tell, what the error is. Maybe, we should write the 2-nd exception handler for it?

Answer (score 0):

Log the error and `die` with custom message

```
error_log($e->getMessage());
die('custom message');
```

Comment: See my edited post, there is always an error message like mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: